# Microsoft Onenote navigation pane for headings

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Anyone know if onenote 2013 has the same navigation pane as you find in microsoft word?
The one that is based on the different heading styles? 
Failing that, I have a page with lots of lines of text, is there a quick way to navigate that page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find addins for OneNote that will add a table of contents but that's as far as it goes. Try looking at the macro's in [OneTastic](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?). There is a [ToC macro](http://www.omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=macroland&id=01C7C254D45E462CB24B3246853B3032) in the existing list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom tags as an alternative to heading styles.
Have different tag for each level of heading and when you search for tags and create a summary page it will be an index of sorts